# Parse json arrays using HIVE query

Tags: arrays, json, hive

I have  json arrays stored in a table (jt) that looks like this:

```
[{"col": 1, "row": 1, "code": "INVESTMENT_PERIOD", "name": "Thời gian đầu tư", "unit": "Năm", "order": 1, "value": 10, "dataType": "INTEGER", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 5}, {"col": 2, "row": 1, "code": "RETIREMENT_FUND", "name": "Số tiền cần có tại thời điểm nghỉ hưu", "unit": "VND", "order": 2, "value": 10000000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 6}, {"col": 1, "row": 2, "code": "INIT_INVESTMENT", "name": "Số tiền đầu tư ban đầu", "unit": "VND", "order": 3, "value": 10000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 4}, {"col": 2, "row": 2, "code": "MONTHLY_INVEST", "name": "Số tiền đầu tư định kỳ", "unit": "VND", "order": 4, "value": 10000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 1}, {"col": 1, "row": 3, "code": "DEPOSIT_TERM", "name": "Ngày nộp tiền định kỳ", "unit": "", "order": 5, "value": 15, "dataType": "INTEGER", "htmlType": "SELECT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 3}]
```

Each array is a record. I would like to parse this table in order to get a new table with multi fields:

- monthly_invest: attributeId = 1 -> value
- execute_date: attributeId = 2 -> value
- deposit_term: attributeId = 3 -> value
- init_investment: attributeId = 4 -> value
- investment_period: attributeId = 5 -> value
- retirement_fund: attributeId = 6 -> value
- investment_fund:attributeId = 7 -> value

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue as follows.

```html
SELECT
    id
    , MAX(monthly_invest)
    , MAX(execute_date)
    , MAX(deposit_term)
    , MAX(init_investment)
    , MAX(investment_period)
    , MAX(retirement_fund)
    , MAX(investment_fund)
FROM
(
SELECT
    'id_test' id
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 1 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END monthly_invest
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 2 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END execute_date
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 3 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END deposit_term
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 4 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END init_investment
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 5 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END investment_period
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 6 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END retirement_fund
    , CASE WHEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.attributeId') = 7 THEN get_json_object(b.new_column, '$.value') END investment_fund
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        split(regexp_replace('[{"col": 1, "row": 1, "code": "INVESTMENT_PERIOD", "name": "Thời gian đầu tư", "unit": "Năm", "order": 1, "value": 10, "dataType": "INTEGER", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 5}, {"col": 2, "row": 1, "code": "RETIREMENT_FUND", "name": "Số tiền cần có tại thời điểm nghỉ hưu", "unit": "VND", "order": 2, "value": 10000000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 6}, {"col": 1, "row": 2, "code": "INIT_INVESTMENT", "name": "Số tiền đầu tư ban đầu", "unit": "VND", "order": 3, "value": 10000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 4}, {"col": 2, "row": 2, "code": "MONTHLY_INVEST", "name": "Số tiền đầu tư định kỳ", "unit": "VND", "order": 4, "value": 10000, "dataType": "FLOAT", "htmlType": "INPUT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 1}, {"col": 1, "row": 3, "code": "DEPOSIT_TERM", "name": "Ngày nộp tiền định kỳ", "unit": "", "order": 5, "value": 15, "dataType": "INTEGER", "htmlType": "SELECT", "targetId": 1, "attributeId": 3}]', '\\[|\\]', ''),'(?<=\\})\\s*,\\s*(?=\\{)') a
) b
LATERAL view explode(b.a) b as new_column
) c
GROUP BY id;
```